# Connect devices to Arduino via WiFi

Tags: arduino, wifi, iot, arduino-uno

I am trying to figure out the best way to control devices in my room through an iPhone app.  For now it would just be things like music and lights but I would like to tackle much more complex systems once I get the hang of it.

I have found a bunch of different resources online that are helping me figure out what parts I need/ where I should start but they all have a different way of doing things.  My biggest question is what board should I use and what other components do I need for the system?  I currently have a few `Arduino Uno's` and am thinking about ordering a `Ethernet Shield 2` to connect to WiFi but then I also found out about the `Arduino Zero` and the `WiFi Shield 10`1 as well as the `MKR1000` which both seem like good options.

If anyone has some advice of where to start of has done something similar I would really appreciate hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

I think below thread can help you.

[Link1](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-control-arduino-board-using-an-android-phone-a/)[Link 2](http://www.instructables.com/id/Making-an-Android-application-for-ArduinoLED-Turn/)[Link3 ][3]

Comment: You missed your Link3.

Comment: I cant add more than 2 since my reputation is low in site

Comment: Do you know how to do it through wifi?